# How to identify table to query in Azure Log Anlytics

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

Newbie to Azure.Let me give some background to my question. I work in a SaaS environment. I have to log into Azure to pull metrics after a job has run successfully.
Each job has 2 tasks associated to it. One tracks when the job started and when it completed. I pull the start and end time so i can calculate duration.
Second task sends a notification to a distribution list confirming the job ran successfully or failed.
I want to be able to use log analytics to run a query to automate this.Pull a report with the jobid, start and end times of the job.Problem is i cannot seem to identify the table that has all the information I need.Any pointers on how to do this would be great. I can see a task table when i go to log analytics but i do not see the start/end times fields.

Comment: Which Azure service are you using to execute your job? Azure Elastic Jobs? Azure Automation Account? ADF ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: TO answer your question @PankajSanwal  The service is Batch Accounts. SO i go to Jobs and under each job i can see the tasks and related info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log analytics as some limitations to it's KQL, E.g. `.show database schema` is not supported, however, I have a few tricks up my sleeve :-)

For all populated tables, for the chosen time period

##### Get number of records per table

```
union withsource=mytable *
| summarize count() by mytable
```

E.g.

| mytable | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| ADAssessmentRecommendation | 244 |
| SigninLogs | 1892 |
| KubePodInventory | 125317 |
| AppServiceHTTPLogs | 84578 |
| SecurityAlert | 1 |

##### Get info of all columns

```
union *
| getschema
```

E.g.

| ColumnName | ColumnOrdinal | DataType | ColumnType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TenantId | 0 | System.String | string |
| SourceSystem | 1 | System.String | string |
| TimeGenerated | 2 | System.DateTime | datetime |
| Computer | 3 | System.String | string |
| Origin | 4 | System.String | string |
| Namespace | 5 | System.String | string |
| Name | 6 | System.String | string |
| Val | 7 | System.Double | real |
| Tags_string | 8 | System.String | string |
| Tags_dynamic | 9 | System.Object | dynamic |

##### Get columns' info per table

This is done in 2 steps.

Execute the following query

```
union withsource=mytable *
| summarize by mytable
| serialize 
| summarize query = strcat_array(make_list(strcat(case(row_number() == 1, "", "| union "), "(", mytable, " | getschema | extend mytable = '", mytable, "')"))," ")
```

E.g.

| query |
| --- |
| (AppServiceAppLogs | getschema | extend mytable = 'AppServiceAppLogs') | union (ADAssessmentRecommendation | getschema | extend mytable = 'ADAssessmentRecommendation') | union (InsightsMetrics | getschema | extend mytable = 'InsightsMetrics') |

Copy-Paste the results and execute

E.g.

```
|    ColumnName     | ColumnOrdinal |    DataType     | ColumnType |          mytable           |
|-------------------|---------------|-----------------|------------|----------------------------|
| TenantId          |             0 | System.String   | string     | AppServiceAppLogs          |
| TimeGenerated     |             1 | System.DateTime | datetime   | AppServiceAppLogs          |
| Level             |             2 | System.String   | string     | AppServiceAppLogs          |
| Host              |             3 | System.String   | string     | AppServiceAppLogs          |
| ResultDescription |             4 | System.String   | string     | AppServiceAppLogs          |
| TenantId          |             0 | System.String   | string     | ADAssessmentRecommendation |
| MG                |             1 | System.String   | string     | ADAssessmentRecommendation |
| SourceSystem      |             2 | System.String   | string     | ADAssessmentRecommendation |
| TenantId          |             0 | System.String   | string     | InsightsMetrics            |
| SourceSystem      |             1 | System.String   | string     | InsightsMetrics            |
| TimeGenerated     |             2 | System.DateTime | datetime   | InsightsMetrics            |
| Computer          |             3 | System.String   | string     | InsightsMetrics            |
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am following your steps. I Appreciate it. Can you recommend study material? I could not find anything that specifically mentioned the .show command doesnt work.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I was finally able to identify the all the columns I needed. I built the KQL query with some online research. I have to do a handon course on KQL.ANy suggestions?

Comment: (1) https://dataexplorer.azure.com/ --> Home --> Explore sample data with KQL (2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sqlcheatsheet (3) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/write-queries (4) https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/kusto-query-language-kql-from-scratch

Comment: I started the pluralsight course. Thank you